# How can I scale up the hatchstyle drawn in a rectangle?

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I'm using .Net drawing to draw a diagram. It is essentially a stacked bar chart.
The issue I have is that I want to reduce the amount of lines in the hatch style so in a way scale it up to make it clearer. I've looked around but didn't come across anything that could help me.

I draw a rectangle and then use a hatchbrush to fill it but due to image size the hatchfill becomes less clearer. Thank you for any suggestions.

The hatchStyles and brush types are stored in the db and I use a helper function to return them. So I draw the rectangle and after getting the brush I fill the rectangle. Essentially I want to scale up the hatch fill if that can be done.

```
 g.DrawRectangle(gridpen, startX, startY, BOREHOLE_RECT_WIDTH, layerRectHeight);

 brush = GetBoreholeBrush(l.SoilTypeMatrixLevel1Id.PrimaryBrushType,
                          l.SoilTypeMatrixLevel1Id.PrimaryFillStyle, 
                          l.SoilTypeMatrixLevel1Id.PrimaryColour);

 g.FillRectangle(brush, startX, startY, BOREHOLE_RECT_WIDTH, layerRectHeight);
```

And the getBrush function; the brush type, hatch style and colour are stored in the db and used to create the returned brush:

```
    //===================================
    private Brush GetBoreholeBrush(string BrushType, string HatchStyle, string Colour)
    //===================================
    {
        //Decide on what brush type has been chosen.
        Brush brush;
        if (BrushType.ToLower() == BrushTypes.HatchBrush.ToString().ToLower())
        {
            brush = new HatchBrush(GetHatchStyle(HatchStyle), 
                                   Color.Black, ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Colour));
        }
        else if (BrushType.ToLower() == BrushTypes.SolidBrush.ToString().ToLower())
        {
            brush = new HatchBrush(GetHatchStyle(HatchStyle), 
                                   Color.Black, ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Colour));
        }
        else if (BrushType.ToLower() == BrushTypes.TextureBrush.ToString().ToLower())
        {
            brush = new HatchBrush(GetHatchStyle(HatchStyle), 
                                   Color.Black, ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Colour));
        }
        else
        {
            brush = new HatchBrush(GetHatchStyle(HatchStyle), 
                                   Color.Black, ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Colour));
        }

        return brush;
    }
```

Function to return the hatch style:

```
   //===================================
    private HatchStyle GetHatchStyle(string FillStyle)
    //===================================
    {
        //Loop through each hatch tyle and return the correct one.
        foreach (HatchStyle style in Enum.GetValues(typeof(HatchStyle)))
        {
            if (style.ToString().ToLower() == FillStyle.ToLower())
            {
                return style;
            }
        }
        return HatchStyle.Vertical;
    }
```

As you can see in the image below the hatch style is not clear.

[image]

Comment: _as the image size increases_ You need to explain this! How is the image size increased? By scaling the image? (Obviously then all pixels get scaled and unsharp, Instead draw it in the right size and then fill..)

Comment: Sorry that was a bad explanation on my part. The image size dose not change. Because its a large image the hatch style becomes less clear and i want to scale it up

Comment: So, essentially, you've got a large chart and your hatchstyle is pixel-small and you want to enlarge the widths of lines and gaps between lines in the hatch sty;e so when your image is i.e. printed or zoomed-out the hatch/lines will still be visible as hatched and not as "grayish"?

Comment: ...but anyways, he code you presented does not help. The important part is how the Brush object is created. Apparently, it sits somewhere inside the `GetBoreholeBrush`, or deeper.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Ive included the code that builds the brush, and yes i want to enlarge the widths so the lines will still be visible.

Comment: Great! Now we see what's going on and **TaW**'s seems to have guessed right. There's not much you can do with HatchBrushes. I'd guess you will need to create your own Brushes here.

Comment: yer i had a feeling id have to create a small image with a filled rectangle using the hatchbrush and then use that image with a texturebrush so i can scale it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most direct but probably not very helpful answer is : No you can't scale the hatch pattern of a `HatchBrush`.

It is meant to always look sharp at the pixel level and is not even affected by scaling the `Graphics` object.

Looking at your question I wonder: Are you sure you are really using a `HatchBrush`? You get the brush from a function `GetBoreholeBrush`. If you really have stored indices into the 50 [HatchStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush.hatchstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then I guess you really use a `HatchBrush`.

Now as using a `HatchBrush` won't work I guess you could use a `TextureBrush` instead..

You could transform the hatch patterns to larger versions by scaling them up; this is not exactly a simple conversion. The direct approach of drawing the larger by an integer factor and without anti-aliasing is simple and may be good enough.

But you may need to fine-tune them, as this way all pixels, that is both **line pixels** and **background pixels** get enlarged and also all diagonals will look jagged.

So you would need to balance the hatch size and the stroke width and recreate all patterns you need from scratch in larger sizes.

Here is an example that illustrates the problems with the simple solution; the first row is the original hatch pattern the others are simple texture brush results, scaled by 1x, 2x and 3x..:

[image]

First a function to transform a `HatchBrush`  to a `TextureBrush`

```
TextureBrush TBrush(HatchBrush HBrush)
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(8,8))
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        G.FillRectangle(HBrush, 0, 0, 8, 8);
        TextureBrush tb = new TextureBrush(bmp);
        return tb;
    }
}
```

Note that the hatch pattern is `8x8` pixels.

Now the `Paint` code used for the above image:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var hs = (HatchStyle[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(HatchStyle));

    for (int i = 0; i < hs.Length; i++)
        using (HatchBrush hbr = new HatchBrush(hs[i], Color.GreenYellow))
        using (HatchBrush hbr2 = new HatchBrush(hs[i], Color.LightCyan))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hbr, new Rectangle(i * 20, 10,16,60));
            using (TextureBrush tbr = TBrush(hbr2))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(tbr, new Rectangle(i * 20, 80, 16, 60));
                tbr.ScaleTransform(2, 2);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(tbr, new Rectangle(i * 20, 150, 16, 60));
                tbr.ResetTransform();
                tbr.ScaleTransform(3,3);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(tbr, new Rectangle(i * 20, 220, 16, 60));
            }
        }
}
```

Note that while the `TextureBrush` has nice methods to modify the texture, the `HatchBrush` has nothing like that at all..