# Disable Antialiasing with HatchBrush?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use `Graphics.FillRectangle` with a `HatchBrush`, drawing on a transparent window with a `ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor` style.

Therefore I must disable the line smoothing that appears when the (diagonal) lines are drawn by the hatch brush, otherwise I get a combined color of the brush's color and Magenta, which is the transparency key color, resulting in a somehow Magenta hatch, regardless of my chosen color.

[image: Magenta pixels surrounding intentionally drawn gray hatch lines]

I have tried various mode properties of my `Graphics` object, without luck.

Comment: Have you tried setting [Graphics.SmoothingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `HighSpeed` or `Default`?

Comment: Yes, this had no effect. Graphics.SmootingMode only seems to affect line drawing.

Comment: Do have a look at [this lengthy discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937643/how-can-i-scale-up-the-hatchstyle-drawn-in-a-rectangle/33938352#33938352) of what a HatchBrush can and can't do  ! Short version: You can't modify it in any way, only workaround with a TextureBrush ..

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link! In the meantime, I have found out that not all hatch styles are affected by antialiasing. My picture above was drawn with `HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal`, when I switched to `HatchStyle.WideDownwardDiagonal`, the problem was gone, and the appearance is nearly the same. Abviously, some hatched are internally drawn using lines, others using bitmap patterns.