# TextureBrush low quality printing

Tags: c#, printing, gdi+

I'm creating an image with some text and using `TextureBrush` for draw the text along a line repeatedly. It is working fine on the screen. when i want to print it, it looks very bad..  I've tried to create the image bigger (relative to the dpi differences) and set its resolution as the resolution of the `Graphics` object (For printing it is higher). Printing the image as it is looks good.. but as `TextureBrush` not so good.

I'm attaching all the prints - Tried to print it to PDF printer - same results as real printer - so no problem there.

first try before changing anything

Drawing the image using `graphics.DrawImage(...)` (The image contains The letter 'A' that I've drew in)

[image: before improving resoultion]

Printing `TextureBrush`

[image]

At this time it was clear that i have resolution problem so I've created my image bigger and in better resolution (as the printer dpi)

Drawing the image using `graphics.DrawImage(...)`

[image]

Looks perfect - Exact size and good quality. `graphics.DrawImage(...)` drew the picture with consideration of its size and resolution.

Now I've used this picture in my `textureBrush`. The result looks like this
[image]

It is bigger because the image itself is bigger - But why it does not consider resolution like `graphics.DrawImage(...)`..
Anyway i've decided to continue and scale down the image using `TextureBrush.ScaleTransform(...)` - The results looks like that

[image]

This is the best that i've reached so far.. I think the main problem is the `TextureBrush` that does not consider the resolution of the image.

I would really prefer to stick with the `TextureBrush` way (And not drawing image by image with clipping and repeating), cause it is very complex code, and complex drawing

Help anyone ?

Comment: a) Not sure but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937643/how-can-i-scale-up-the-hatchstyle-drawn-in-a-rectangle/33938352#33938352) could be of interest  b) drawimage does honor the dpi resolution of the bitmap it draws. Maybe TextureBrush does that too?? (Btw it is not only the size but the dpi (bitmap.SetResolution) that matters. Maybe yopu could post some code?

Comment: a) not helping. b) I would really be happy if `TextureBrush` would honor the dpi.. but sadly i didn't find any way to tell him that.. About posting the code, it is complicated, cause the printing is being initiated by 3rd party i'm using, and the drawing the letter to image, and using `TextureBrush` and such are pretty basics (If you want a specific part I would post). I'm sadly starting to implement an alternative drawing repeatedly image with clipping :'(

Comment: Yup, just did a few tests and must confirm that TextureBrush doesn't honor the dpi of the base image. Pity. Good luck! Did you consider using a larger brush and doing a ScaleTransform __on the Graphics object that uses the brush__. This looks nice here, but I didn't test when printing..

Comment: Do you mean `ScaleTransform` of the `TextureBrush` ? Yes i did.. this is the best results that i've got.. as written in my question

Comment: No. As I wrote I meant  ScaleTransform on the Graphics object that uses the brush. A bit of a hassle to get those coordinates right, though.

Comment: Yeah, well, i guess i will get the same result in the printing as scaling the `TextureBrush`. But anyway, I have to say.. I gave up and made my manual `TextureBrush` using allot of matrix manipulations..